# NPM Authentication Error To Private Repo on jenkins build

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, npm

I'm working on a Front End Application that relies on a dependency developed by our organization but is hosted in a separate repository. It's a bitbucket repo hosted by us and is private.

We're using NPM to manage this dependency, and install it via `git+https://<the-dependency-repo>.com`

This works in our local environment because our credentials are cached. Please note: **WE CANNOT SWITCH TO SSH**. I'm aware of the ssh solution, I have no control over account management, bitbucket access etc...

When the Jenkins CI runs, it pulls our application from it's repository using credentials stored in the Credentials Plugin, and runs `npm install`.

**The Problem:**

The install fails because of authentication failure during the `npm install`.

**What I've tried so far:**

Since the git credentials are stored in the Jenkins Credential Plugin, I have access to a git username/password combination.

The precise failure happens when npm attempts to run `git ls-remote ...`

To circumvent this authentication failure, I am able to run a shell command before the npm install:

```
git config credential.helper 'cache'
git fetch https://${USERPASSCOMBO}@<repo>
```

The good news is that this works! NPM is able to run `git fetch ls-remote` without error

The bad news is that the next command `git clone -q <repo>` fails.

I've attempted the same solution: adding the following prior to npm install:

```
 git config credential.helper 'cache'
 git ls-remote https://${USERPASSCOMBO}@<repo>
 git clone https://${USERPASSCOMBO}@<repo>
```

*note: these commands work as expected, prior to npm install*

NPM install still fails however, producing the following error output:

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! Command failed: /bin/git clone -q https://<repo> /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-ed5ac1a9
[ERROR] npm ERR! warning: templates not found /tmp/pacote-git-template-tmp/git-clone-49feabe4
[ERROR] npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for '<repo>'
[ERROR] npm ERR!
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, even a pointer towards the right direction. I've exhausted trying everything I can think of.

Comment: Was you able to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: I have similar circumstances. I hope this question gets answered.

Answer (score -2):

Try installing from the repository with the URL `git+https://user:password@<repo-url>`.
Note that this leaves your password out in the open, so I suggest generating an app token or similar if your repository provider supports this.